# What could this plant be ? It’s leaves smell citrus when crushed

Tags: identification

Can someone recognize this plant for me ? It’s leaves have a citrus smell to them.[image]

Comment: Can you tell us what part of the world it is growing in and how tall it is?

Answer (score 1):

Yes if it's growing eg in a Mediterranean country it could be that a lemon, or orange tree is starting to grow there...Otherwise lemon balm and lemon verbena both have a distinct lemony citrus smell!

Comment: The plants you mentioned seem to have leaves of different shape than this one. You need to provide supportive data.